# How to configure custom ejabberd roster module?

Tags: ejabberd

I have to replace the standard mod_roster with my own custom roster. I wrote the module and see that it loads because it's start function is called by no other functions are called.

I also tried putting log output in all the methods of the standard mod_roster but I can't see any methods called which I log in using the Adium client.

Has anyone configured a custom roster module in ejabberd? Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for {mod_roster, []}, in the ejabberd.cfg file and replace mode_roster with your module.